# Start new activity broken by AdMob?

Tags: android, android-activity, admob

So i added AdMob to my app and now it will not start the next activity by pressing a button.
I am trying to press a button in the Main Activity so it goes to Second Activity.
It worked before i added Admob

Main Activity:

```
 private AdView adView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);






      // Create an ad.
      adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "XXXXXXXXXXXX");

      // Add the AdView to the view hierarchy. The view will have no size
      // until the ad is loaded.
      RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main1);
      layout.addView(adView);

      // Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed device ID to
      // get test ads on a physical device.
      AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
      adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);

      // Start loading the ad in the background.
      adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    /** Called before the activity is destroyed. */
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
      // Destroy the AdView.
      if (adView != null) {
        adView.destroy();
      }

      super.onDestroy();







    Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), PartyRockScreen.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }

    });
}
}
```

Second Activity:

```
private AdView adView2;

  @Override
  public void onBackPressed() {

    }
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.party);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);



          // Create an ad.
          adView2 = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "XXXXXXXXXXXX");

          // Add the AdView to the view hierarchy. The view will have no size
          // until the ad is loaded.
          RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.party1);
          layout.addView(adView2);

          // Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed device ID to
          // get test ads on a physical device.
          AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
          adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);

          // Start loading the ad in the background.
          adView2.loadAd(adRequest);
        }

        /** Called before the activity is destroyed. */
        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
          // Destroy the AdView.
          if (adView2 != null) {
            adView2.destroy();
          }

          super.onDestroy();









        final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.partyrock);
        mediaPlayer.start(); // no need to call prepare(); create() does that for you




        ViewFlipper mFlipper;
        mFlipper = ((ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.flipper));
        mFlipper.setAutoStart(true);
        mFlipper.startFlipping();
        mFlipper.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), android.R.anim.fade_in));
        mFlipper.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), android.R.anim.fade_out));

        ViewFlipper mFlipper1;
        mFlipper1 = ((ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.flipper1));
        mFlipper1.setAutoStart(true);
        mFlipper1.startFlipping();
        mFlipper1.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), android.R.anim.fade_in));
        mFlipper1.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), android.R.anim.fade_out));




        Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();                 
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();








                    }

                        });

                };
            }
```

Comment: That was not a very helpful answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it -

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PartyRockScreen.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Comment: @SnoX, how? I'm having the same issue

Comment: @SnoX, thanks but I got it since late last night! (can't recall how right now, at work!)